# Hide a secure view completely in MediaProjection - android

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediacodec, android-mediaprojection

I'm creating a screen recorder app using the MediaProjection API. In my app, I'm showing the stop button as a small overlay window. I've kept this view as secure so that it doesn't come up in the final recorded video.

This view doesn't come up in the final video, but the final output is itself a black area in place of the original view.

Is it any way possible to get the final video output without this black area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to do that currently unless you have System permission.

Comment: How to do that even in case of System permissions?

Comment: See `frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/display/OverlayDisplayAdapter.java` and related code

Comment: @omerjerk I want to do the same thing. Could you find a way to do it?

Comment: There's no way without root at least. And I haven't tried what @reker suggested yet.

Comment: @reker, could edit your answer with a code example please? I not understood > "`See frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/display/OverlayDisplayAdapter.java and related code`".

Comment: @omerjerk, you already tried this suggestion?

Comment: @Coringa No, why?

Answer (score 1):

I found a link related to hiding the overlay when requesting mediaProjection but the problem is app needs to be a system app and require a system permission `android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER` and flag `PRIVATE_FLAG_HIDE_NON_SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOWS` not seems to be available to application developers. Have a look on this page to see if you can get anywhere.
https://review.lineageos.org/c/LineageOS/android_frameworks_base/+/239014/2

Comment: Or [**PRIVATE_FLAG_IS_ROUNDED_CORNERS_OVERLAY**](https://blog.xzr.moe/archives/136/). [Eg](https://gerrit.pixelexperience.org/plugins/gitiles/frameworks_base/+/017adb2dfb0f0147a5f7bf746a62f66f1d290fc3/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/ScreenDecorations.java#239)