# How AirDroid Business is able to exclude overlay from screenshot?

Tags: android, screenshot, android-mediaprojection

Someone know how they achieved it?

They using [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection) apis to capture device screen, but one people here on SO said that these apis not offer this feature (exclude overlay).

Then how they achieved this  success?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Patent applications are public 18 months after being filed, so it's a start.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh! this is same case of TeamViewer:

- *[How teamviewer native touch works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379102/android-how-teamviewer-native-touch-works)*
- *[How does TeamViewer take screenshots and allow remote control without root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954825/how-does-teamviewer-take-screenshots-and-allow-remote-control-without-root)*
- *[Hide a secure view completely in MediaProjection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71625708/16631852)* - And this is a possible solution (supposedly also made on *AirDroid Business*)!